# Change preloaded images in jquery

Tags: jquery, click, preloader

I am trying to change images out on a click. The images should be preloaded, but I can't even tell if they are preloading. New to Jquery please help.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
 var preloads = [
    'images/01.jpg',
    'images/02.jpg',
    'images/03.jpg',
    'images/04.jpg',
    'images/05.jpg',
 ]; 

 $(preloads).each(function(){
     $('')[0].src=this;
 });
 var i = 0;


});

$("img").click(function() {
    ++i;
    if(i = 17)  {
        i = 0;
    }
    $(this).src = preloads[i];
});
</script>
```

Comment: Check the ``Network`` tab in your browser's developer panel to see when the request is actually being made.

Comment: I have, and it does not appear to be loading anything except for my first image which is in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with what you have. Firstly, you can't specify a `src` for a `<script>` tag with a body, because then it won't execute what you have inside the tag, only what is loaded from the source. Secondly, change the line `$('')[0].src = this;` to `$('<img/>').get(0).src = val;` and change the function declaration to `function (i, val) {` so that you're passing the string affiliated with each index of the array.

So, here's the solution:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var preloads = [
      'images/01.jpg',
      'images/02.jpg',
      'images/03.jpg',
      'images/04.jpg',
      'images/05.jpg',
    ];

    $(preloads).each(function(i, val) {
      $('<img/>').get(0).src = val;
    });
    var i = 0;

    $("img").click(function() {
      ++i;
      if (i = 17) {
        i = 0;
      }
      $(this).get(0).src = preloads[i];
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, now I see that it is loading the images, but the click to change src still isn't working. Any ideas on that?